# the trigonometric "z" component on a unit sphere

Tags: trigonometry

i have a question that might seem a bit silly but here it is. it's been a little while since i learned that:

> $\cos$ on the unit circle is the $x$ coordinate of that point, and same thing with $\sin$, which is the $y$ coordinate.

But what about trigonometry of a sphere? What can we say about the $z$ component of it?

Second, I've learned about the tangent and that it is the line that intersects the circle in one point, and is perpendicular with it, and that it can be used to determine the slope.

But is there anything else to it? I don't know i kinda think there is much more usage of it?

Comment: Look for information about spherical coordinates, and maybe compare that to what you recall about polar coordinates. Be careful of your variables: the $x$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle is the cosine of an angle, but that's not "cos of $x$". We'd usually use another variable like $\theta$ or $t$ for the angle, so $x = \cos \theta$.

Comment: thank you very much sir or ma'am

Comment: You see how simple the definitions of sine and cosine are, yet they are some of the most widely applied of all non-algebraic functions. You will encounter them everywhere, including in many applications where triangles and circles are not immediately apparent (they are always hiding somewhere behind the scenes, though). Why would you think the tangent would be any different? Yes, that is all there is to the definition, but also yes, the tangent function has an impressively broad number of applications.